# Определение метода для вычисления наименьшего расстояния точки содержащегося в теле объектного типа

Tags: sql, oracle

Имеется фигура в трехмерном пространстве. Создала объектный тип для вершины `apex_type`:

```
CREATE TYPE apex_type AS OBJECT
(
c_x BINARY_FLOAT,
c_y BINARY_FLOAT,
c_z BINARY_FLOAT
);
```

Далее, для фигуры создала так же объектный тип, но теперь содержащий еще метод, который должен вычислять наименьшее расстояние до точки, находящейся на фигуре, от плоскости (например: X – 0 - Y).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE аigure AS OBJECT
(
v_1 apex_type,
v_2 apex_type,
v_3 apex_type,
MEMBER FUNCTION interval RETURN BINARY_FLOAT
);
```

Далее необходимо определить метод `interval()` и тут я встряла, не смогла разобраться.

Имеется конструктор запроса:

```
CREATE  [OR REPLACE]  TYPE  BODY < Имя типа >
AS
(MEMBER FUNCTION <Тело программы>;)
End;
```

Стала прописывать запрос согласно конструктору, получила следующее:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY figure AS
MEMBER FUNCTION interval RETURN BINARY_FLOAT
IS
BEGIN
...
END;
```

Не смогла разобраться как именно необходимо прописать условие вычисления самого расстояния, которое, как я понимаю, должно прописываться между `begin` и `end`.

Comment: У вас, как и в предыдушем вопросе, используется термин _конструктор_. Что вы под ним понимаете?

Comment: Так скажем определенное клише которому следует придерживаться при составлении определенного запроса. Если взять просто как пример вывод данных (select* from <имя схемы.имя таблицы>), то согласно такому конструктору можно понять, что после from необходимо указать имя таблицы из которой планируется вывод данных.

Comment: Может прототип лучше, конструктор это ключевое слово и служит для инициализации сущностей объектных типов или коллекций.

Comment: Не совсем понял, что вы желаете в метод `interval()` реализовать, что это за пример - `X – 0 - Y`? Что конкретно не получается?

Comment: Хорошо, вот [работающий прототип](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=32f044f42fce98ccea4c88cf36cf15d6). Что там не понятно, что ожидается вместо 0.0? Уточните в вопросе, или поместите в комментарии изменённую ссылку.

Comment: Смотрите, забыла в скрипте еще указать, что имеется помимо фигуры еще точка в пространстве и мне необходимо найти расстояние от этой точки до точек вершин фигуры.
Вот [скрипты](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ce3ce9f12fdd8b21709b6e41e9426b55) которые выполняю

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что вы учите,  объектные типы или геометрию? Где вы это взяли: `EXTRACT (COORD FROM SELF.v_1)`?

Comment: отрывками из просторов интернета

Comment: Какие-то непонятные отрывки. А первый вопрос, что вы сейчас учите?

Comment: Объекты в oracle, просто за основу взято задание одного из преподавателей.

Comment: Так это две разные задачи, одна с другой не связаны. Сначала надо разобратся с алгоритмом расчёта растояния, независимо от языка программирования. Потом уже имплементировать в методе объекта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Упростим задачу, найдём расстояния между вершиной и другой точкой в пространстве:

```
create or replace type point as object (
    x binary_float,
    y binary_float,
    z binary_float)
/
create or replace type vertex as object (
    p point,
    member function distance (p point) return binary_float
)
/
create or replace type body vertex as 
    member function distance (p point) return binary_float is
    begin 
        return sqrt (
            power (self.p.x - p.x, 2) + 
            power (self.p.y - p.y, 2) + 
            power (self.p.z - p.z, 2));
    end;
end;
/
```

Как посмотереть в действии:

```
declare 
    v vertex := vertex (p=>point (x=>1, y=>-2, z=>3));
begin
    dbms_output.put_line ('result='||v.distance (point (x=>-3, y=>2, z=>-1)));
end;
/
```

> result=6,92820311E+000

Comment: Спасибо!
Я пошла немного по другому пути, не знаю насколько он корректен. При создании типа vertex я задала две точки (т.е вершину и точку) и в методе указала, что координаты точки вычитаются из координат вершины. 
Далее создала таблицу и в одном из столбцов указала данный тип - vertex.
Добавила записи в таблицу, но при обращении к методу у меня выходит ошибка: ORA-06553: PLS-306: ошибочно число или типы аргументов при обращении к 'DISTANCE'
Подскажите корректно ли так делать? Я имею ввиду указывать точку вершины и точку в пространстве в одном объектном типе и использовать далее в таблице?

Comment: @Лидия а) _Я пошла немного по другому пути_, я дал только путь реализации, т.е. сделал минимальный воспроизводимый пример, а не пытался вашу задачу по геометрии решить в полном объёме. б)  _указывать точку вершины и точку в пространстве в одном объектном типе и использовать далее в таблице_, думаю да, можно. Но я не могу угадать, _как вы это сделали_. Поэтому, задайте новый вопрос, или хотя бы нерабочий пример на фиддле (ссылка есть под вопросом).

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2fbd2b5e32eb3aa0d9e1e576249f3086
Но фидл ругается на запрос с телом объекта, хотя sql developer принял его без проблем.

Comment: Слеш забыли - [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=68c0bcc2e7dd1a92559c25e80eb0cc4e).

Comment: Точно, спасибо!

Comment: @Лидия Рад был помочь! В следующий раз будете задавать вопрос, включайте ссылку на фиддл. Быстрее разобраться можно, что не получается.